# Is there a more proper word for the concept of 'interyear'?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice

I am describing a difference in one value between two different years.

I'd like to put this into a single word and it came to my mind to just use the prefix `inter-` along with `year`.

I mean, it *feels* grammatically correct ...

However, I've never seen it in real life and a google search returns less than 100 results, so I think it would be better to try to use a differente, much more common, word (if it exists).

Comment: interannual: occuring between two or more years. Used in accounting, for example.

Comment: That's the one! Also yeah, I'm doing an accounting excercise.

Comment: ... Year-on-year.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Yes. That's the one most often used in the accountancy profession - eg. *The year-on-year comparison shows an increase in sales of 14%*.

Comment: I've not given it as an answer because it doesn't specify 'a difference in one value between **two** different years', but between years n, n+1, n+2 ....

Comment: Another similar phrase is "year-over-year".